# Intersection of Parabolas for Voronoi Diagram

Tags: python, roblox, voronoi

This is my first question on Stack Overflow, so if I have formatted something incorrectly or not added the correct information, please let me know and I will fix it when I can.

I'm trying to implement Fortune's Algorithm for creating a Voronoi Diagram in Roblox. Roblox uses a more limited version of Lua, so I can't just import modules or copy-paste most code. Fortune's Algorithm uses parabolas to find the points required to make the edges around each site and I found an [equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QpC4.png) in [Fortunes Algorithm: An intuitive explanation](https://jacquesheunis.com/post/fortunes-algorithm/) that generates a parabola where every point on the parabola is equidistant from the focus and the directrix.

​I know how to find the intersection of two parabolas when they are in standard form, but I have been unable to get the above equation into standard form. I've tried (on paper) putting it on both sides of the equals sign, setting it equal to zero, then expanding the polynomials using wolframAlpha's polynomial expander, producing

```
[(-X^2 * fx) + (X^2 * f'y) + (2 * dy * fx * X) - (2 * dy * f'x * X) + (2 * f'x * fy * X) - (2 * fx * f'y * X) + (dy^2 * fy) - (dy^2 * f'y) - (dy * fy^2) + (dy * f'y^2) - (fy * f'y^2) + (f'y * fy^2) + (dy * f'x^2) - (f'x^2 * fy) - (dy * fx^2) + (f'y * fx^2)] / [2(dy^2) - (dy * fy) - (dy * f'x) + (fy * f'y))]
```

where X is a variable, fx and fy are the x and y coordinates of the first focus, f'x and f'y are the x and y coordinates of the second focus, and dy is the y coordinate of the directrix. I am unsure of where to go from here.

I asked this on Stack Overflow in the hopes of finding someone who has implemented it before, but I may also ask it on a more math-related website as I just need the formula that gives the intercept(s). Having said this, if anyone has a code answer to this, Python would be preferred as I am most familiar with it.

Unrelated to the main question, does anyone know if there is a way to format the equation in Stack Overflow that is more easy to look at than a single line, and if so, how?

Comment: What are the two equations you are trying to find the intersection from? You mention a formula from the image attached, but then you seem to be using another one which is not shown.

Comment: It’s a totally fair question so don’t feel like you have to move it but I suspect you’ll find more mathy people on https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DeusDev I don't think I entirely understand what you mean, but inputting values as x into the equation in the image gives me resulting y-values that lie on a parabola, and that is as far as I have gotten. What I need is be able to find the intersection of two of those parabolas mathematically since brute-forcing it and testing every possible point with the equation I have doesn't seem like a good option.

Comment: @GrantCurell thank you, I will take a look there and see what I can find

Comment: @HereForABit I made the Math and got a result for the intersection. If you make a question somewhere where I can answer using LaTeX send me the link and I'll make the post.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DeusDev I have now made a similar question on math.stackexchange.com that will probably allow you to use LaTeX in your answer. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4559968/intersection-of-parabolas-for-voronoi-diagram

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Python, but I've solved this problem with Lua:

The function needs focus 1 and focus 2, also the directrix Y as Furtune's sweep line.

```
local function getParabolaCrossPoint (focus1, focus2, dirY) -- focus 1, focus 2, directrix Y
    -- extract x and y coordinates of the foci:
    local p1x, p1y = focus1.x, focus1.y
    local p2x, p2y = focus2.x, focus2.y
    -- calculate the focal length (half the distance from the focus to the directrix) for both foci:
    local f1, f2 = math.abs(dirY-p1y)/2, math.abs(dirY-p2y)/2
    -- calculate the a, b, c coefficients as parabolas difference:
    local a1, a2 = -1/(4*f1), -1/(4*f2)
    local b1, b2 = -2*p1x*a1, -2*p2x*a2
    local c1, c2 = p1x*p1x*a1 + p1y + f1, p2x*p2x*a2 + p2y + f2
    -- calculate the coefficients for the combined parabola formed by subtracting the second parabola from the first:
    local a, b, c = a1-a2, b1-b2, c1-c2
    -- calculate the discriminant to determine the number of intersection points:
    local d = b*b-4*a*c
    if d >=0 then
        -- calculate the x-coordinate of the intersection point:
        local x1 = (-b-math.sqrt (d))/(2*a)
--      local x2 = (-b+math.sqrt (d))/(2*a)
        -- calculate the y-coordinate of the intersection point using the equation of the first parabola:
        local y = a1*x1*x1 + b1*x1 + c1
        -- return the intersection point coordinates (just left one):
        return x1, y
    end
end
```